# Date difference in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

May be this question is dumb one or repeated one but I didnt get exact answe for this

I have table which has date format column(eff_date), I want the data where difference between sysdate anda eff_date is more than two years and equal to two years

I am using this query I know its syntactically wrong

```
select * 
from Customer 
where (select floor(months_between(sysdate,eff_date)/12) 
       from Customer t) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `months_between`

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer
 WHERE months_between( sysdate, eff_date ) >= 24
```

If there is an index on `eff_date`, though, you probably want

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer
 WHERE eff_date <= sysdate - interval '2' year
```

Comment: Okay thanks For the reply . what do you mean by index .. ? I the first one you suggested and second one is giving different results I think first one is correct answer .. I tried one answer, Correct if I am wrong.. `select * from (select t.*,floor(months_between(sysdate,eff_date)/12) as date_diff from Customer t) where date_diff>=2`

Comment: @aravind - Sorry, I forgot to reverse the `>=` operator.  Corrected the second answer.  An index is a structure in the database whose purpose is to make queries more efficient by letting queries search for particular rows in `O(log N)` time rather than reading every row in the table which is `O(n)`.  If there is an index on `eff_date`, the first query will not be able to use it-- it will need to scan the entire table.  The second query might be able to use the index depending on your data distribution.

Comment: Wow thanks first one is working good.. One more question there will be any problem if any year is a Leap year ?

Comment: @aravind - There won't be a problem assuming you want to treat leap years the same way that `months_between` treats leap years (which is generally what most people mean).  `months_between( date '2006-02-28', date '2004-02-29')` returns exactly 24.